# Understanding BitTorrent Pieces Output

Tags: python, sha1, bittorrent

After using https://github.com/utdemir/bencoder to extract the metainfo from a single file torrent I am seeing the following text under the "pieces" section of the output-

`This is an abbreviated portion of the output-
'pieces':'\x8f1g\xdb\x1e\x17\n(\xf9\xbb\xb0&\xa0\xadT9N\xa8L\x89\x97\xf79\x15\x07N`

And after looking at https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification I am under the understanding that this output is-

> [a] string consisting of the concatenation of all 20-byte SHA1 hash values, one per piece (byte string, i.e. not urlencoded)

However I am seeing the constant backslashes "\" and am wondering if this is something like hexadecimal codes since SHA-1 commonly outputs to hexadecimal?

Comment: yup, bytes represented as hexa when ascii isn't possible

Comment: Yes, those are bytes in their hex representation. Try putting '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f' in a Python shell (or b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f' if you're using Python3.)

Comment: @kirbuchi if the letter "g" is included in these representations wouldn't that be outside the scope of hex since hex ends at "f" in letter representations

Comment: @CJCahala you can mix the ascii letter and hex representation in a Python bytestring (e.g. `b'\x68ello'`) the \ escapes the next two characters and considers them to be the the hex representation of the next byte.

Comment: *"SHA-1 commonly outputs to hexadecimal"* how many characters does a hex sha1 output have? And how many bytes per hash does the spec say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you see from the program is encoded as a [Python bytesliteral](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings),
were non printable bytes and ASCII is escaped.

`\x8f1g\xdb\x1e\x17\n(\xf9\xbb\xb0&\xa0\xadT9N\xa8L\x89\x97\xf79\x15\x07N`

`\x8f` => hexadecimal 0x8F
`1g` => ASCII "1g"
`\xdb\x1e\x17` => hexadecimal 0xDB1E17
`\n` => Escape Sequence meaning ASCII Linefeed (LF)  (hexadecimal 0x0A)
`(` => ASCII "("
`\xf9\xbb\xb0` => hexadecimal 0xF9BBB0
etc.